# Document Discussion in SharePoint 2013

Tags: document, discussion-board

My users like to have threaded discussions about documents in a document library.  For example, as a policy is developed. they have a forum based discussion - without the discussion happening *in* the document.

In SharePoint 2010, this can be achieved with a third party add-in, http://www.hhogdev.com/Products/Document-Discussion-2010/Overview.aspx.

Does anybody know if this can be achieved in SharePoint 2013, or using any social add-ons?  Many thanks!

Comment: The link to the third-party add-in is unavailable

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to add the existing field "Append-Only Comments" to your document library and activate versioning. Than you have the same behaviour like the "Comments"-Column in the "Issue Tracking"-List. Everytime a user edits an item the user can add a new comment with username and timestamp.
Sure, you don't have the same features like the discussion board, but the rudimentary functionallity is given.

Screen 1:
[image]

Screen 2:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is available OOTB (Out-of-the-box) in SharePoint 2010, you do NOT need a third party add-in:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/create-customize-and-moderate-a-discussion-board-HA101808839.aspx

It appears there is even MORE social network software built into SharePoint 2013:

http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/Pages/Overview.aspx#share

Comment: Hi Doug,  Thanks but not quite what we're after.  This is the discussious boards, but what there doesn't seem to be is a mechasim to tie a discussion to a document.  Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to tie it to a specific document. Got it. Well, you can always create a Document Workspace for each document, this is basically a sub-site for each document with discussion groups, etc. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/54db21/document-workspace-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Aren't Document workspaces deprecated in 2013?